# Execute python script from my java android app

Tags: java, android, python

I have an app in mind that will run various python scrpits. 
But I have a problem running python scripts from my java code.
 I tried to use [QPython](http://qpython.com/), but I will have to start new intent to run my python code. That's not a problem but I have to close QPython intent manually to receive console output back to my app. That's not go.
 Also I looked at [sl4a](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a) and its fork [android scripting](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) but I didn't find any examples of how can I do such a thing from my JAVA code. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar issue with QPython. Could you tell me if and how you could resolve this? Also, is there some sample code you could post?

Comment: I didn't found the solution and gave up on my little app, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/

It does exactly what you need but their licensing process is very unfriendly.
I have the same issue and I'm still unable to find another solution, although because of the licensing, I'm not going to use it.

As an idea I'm thinking of making a service completely in python using kivy and all the rest in java, but I can't yet find an example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sampleproject which shows how to execute python scripts on your android devices.

https://github.com/qpython-android/AndroidApp-with-qpython-API

Comment: Yeah, thanks you, but I already checked it out. It doesnt'do what I need it to do. It opens new activity, which I have to manually close, which is not acceptable.