# Is there a way to integrate a python script to a button in android studio?

Tags: python, android, frontend, backend

I’m working on this face recognition app, so I am using android studio as front-end and python as a back-end.Upon designing my UI in android studio, I want to make a button in a way when i press it , my python script runs. If someone can help me I’d be very grateful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use an api to call ur backend

Answer (score 1):

What I think you need to do is run your python script on a server,

Then make a GET request from your app, on click or whatever, then out the response (generally in JSON) from your script.py

Comment: How exactly can i do this, sorry i  am still a beginner is there a tutorial or something you can help me more. I would be grateful

Comment: This link might be helpfull  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479280/execute-python-script-from-my-java-android-app

Comment: Here is a sample about what you need : https://github.com/qpython-android/app-call-qpython-api

Comment: Another example : https://github.com/ericdecanini/HelloChaquopy